# How to setup ipv6 link-local address on docker composer

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ipv6

I am wondering if there is any way to set statically the link-local of a container in docker-composer. I can set a global address using "ipv6_address" but could not find a way to set a local one.
I tried:
(...)
ipv6_address: fe80::1
(...)
but docker compose returns: Invalid address fe80::1: It does not belong to any of this network's subnets.

Answer (score 0):

The IPv6 link scope addresses are built from the mac address. Just set the mac address using mac_address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx